# HTML email font size decrease on mobile because of header navigation

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

All:

When I include a header navigation bar which is made up of inline jpegs in my html email, the fonts in the rest of the email render incredibly small regardless of my media queries. When I remove the header bar they render fine.

So there is something about the way that I have built the header that is causing this weird issue and I have tried every possible (in my mind) permutation and can't find a fix. Help would be much appreciated.

Here are screen shots of the mobile email with and without the header.

https://ibb.co/g1i9vH

https://ibb.co/fy8W9c

And here is my code:

```
<!-- Helm Email Template -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style type="text/css">
/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

/* RESET STYLES */
img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

/* iOS BLUE LINKS */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .mobile-center {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .text-resp {
        font-size: 14px!important;
    }
}

/* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] { margin: 0 !important; }
</style>
<body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">

<!-- HIDDEN PREHEADER TEXT -->
<div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 1px; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus dolor aliquid omnis consequatur est deserunt, odio neque blanditiis aspernatur, mollitia ipsa distinctio, culpa fuga obcaecati!
</div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
        <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
        <![endif]-->
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">              

        <!-- Start Header -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="width: background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;" bgcolor="red" height="30">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                            <a href="https://helmboots.com/collections/shop"><img style="display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width:99px;" src="https://image.ibb.co/bODCyS/header_menu_men.png" alt="Men"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                            <a href="https://helmboots.com/collections/womens"><img style="display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width:122px;" src="https://image.ibb.co/gSEwQ7/header_menu_women.png" alt="Women"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                           <a href="https://helmboots.com/"><img style="display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 148px;" src="https://image.ibb.co/gc0357/header_logo.png" alt="Helm"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                          <a href="https://helmboots.com/collections/supply"><img style="display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 123px;" src="https://image.ibb.co/iEU7Xn/header_menu_supply.png" alt="Supply"></a>
                         </td>
                        <td align="center" style="line-height:0px;">
                          <a href="https://helmboots.com/collections/sale"><img style="display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 108px;" src="https://image.ibb.co/nMdedS/header_menu_sale.png" alt="Sale"></a>
                        </td>   

                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>          
            <!-- End Header -->            

            <!-- Start Spacer -->  
            <tr>
                <td height="40" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
            </tr>          
            <!-- End Spacer -->

            <!-- Start Section 1: Hero Image -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="http://helmboots.com"><img style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/iTNSXn/content_image_1.jpg" alt="img"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 1: Hero Image -->             

            <!-- Start Section 2: Proof Point #1 Image  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <img style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/bRxrqH/helm_email_1_section_2_img_1.png" alt="img">
                        </td>
                    </tr>                  
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 2: Proof Point #1 Image  -->   

            <!-- Start Section 2: Proof Point #1 Copy  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <p class="text-resp" style="font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:16px; color:#3d3d3d; line-height:30px;" mc:edit="Paragraph">
                            HELM boots don’t complete your look, they make it. Every pair has been designed with simplicity in mind, making them perfect for every style and occasion.   
                        </p>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 2: Proof Point #1 Copy  -->  

            <!-- Start Section 2: Proof Point #2 Image  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <img style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/b1zkjc/helm_email_1_section_2_img_2.png" alt="img">
                        </td>
                    </tr>                  
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 2: Proof Point #2 Image  -->   

            <!-- Start Section 2: Proof Point #2 Copy  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%" style=" width: 90%; max-width:400px;">
                    <tr>
                        <p class="text-resp" style="width: 90%; max-width:400px; font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:16px; color:#3d3d3d; line-height:30px;" mc:edit="Paragraph">
                            Reliable boots that look good are hard to come by. We combine a timeless aesthetic with the best materials on earth to create boots that are designed to fit your style for years to come. 
                        </p>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 2: Proof Point #2 Copy  -->     

            <!-- Start Section 2: Proof Point #3 Image  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <img style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/hjN2xx/helm_email_1_section_2_img_3.png" alt="img">
                        </td>
                    </tr>                  
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 2: Proof Point #3 Image  -->   

            <!-- Start Section 2: Proof Point #3 Copy  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%" style=" width: 90%; max-width:400px;">
                    <tr>
                        <p class="text-resp" style="width: 90%; max-width:400px; font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:16px; color:#3d3d3d; line-height:30px;" mc:edit="Paragraph">
                            We want you to love your first pair of HELM boots. We offer free shipping and free exchanges until you find that perfect pair. And of course, returns are on us too.
                        </p>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 2: Proof Point #3 Copy  -->  

            <!-- Start Spacer -->  
            <tr>
                <td height="80" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
            </tr>          
            <!-- End Spacer -->

            <!-- Start Section 3: Video -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                                            <a href="https://helmboots.com/#shopify-section-1516337993723"><img class="g-img" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;" src="https://image.ibb.co/huJZCn/content_image_2.jpg" alt="img"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 3: Video -->  

            <!-- Start Spacer -->  
            <tr>
                <td height="40" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
            </tr>          
            <!-- End Spacer -->                                   

            <!-- Start Section 3: Video Copy  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%" style=" width: 90%; max-width:400px;">
                    <tr>
                        <p class="text-resp" style="width: 90%; max-width:400px; font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:16px; color:#3d3d3d; line-height:30px;" mc:edit="Paragraph">
                            Some say clothes make the man, we think it’s the boots. Our boots give men confidence from the ground up, confidence to take steps they’ve never taken before.
                        </p>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 3: Video Copy  --> 

            <!-- Start Spacer -->  
            <tr>
                <td height="80" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
            </tr>          
            <!-- End Spacer -->                        

            <!-- Start Section 4: Shop Muller Teak -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="https://helmboots.com/collections/shop/products/muller-blucher-teak"><img style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px; max-width: 450px; width: 100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/m9QZdS/content_image_3.jpg" alt="img"></a>                                                                   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Section 4: Shop Muller Teak --> 

            <!-- Start Spacer -->  
            <tr>
                <td height="80" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
            </tr>          
            <!-- End Spacer -->                           

            <!-- Start Footer Jargon  -->            
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%" style=" width: 90%; max-width:400px;">
                    <tr>
                        <p style=" padding: 0 5%; width: 90%; max-width:600px; font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#3d3d3d; line-height:22px;" mc:edit="Paragraph">
                            Copyright © 2018 HELM Boots. All rights reserved.<br>You are receiving this email because you signed up at www.helmboots.com
                        </p>
                        <p style=" padding: 0 5%; width: 90%; max-width:600px; font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#3d3d3d; line-height:22px;" mc:edit="Paragraph">
                            HELM Boots<br> 1200 East 11th St. <br>Suite 101 <br>Austin, TX 78701
                        </p>                        
                        <p style=" padding: 0 5%; width: 90%; max-width:600px; font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#3d3d3d; line-height:22px;" mc:edit="Paragraph">
                            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #3d3d3d;" href="*|UNSUB|*">Unsubscribe from this list</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #3d3d3d;" href="#">Update subscription preferences</a>
                        </p>                                           
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Footer Jargon  -->             


        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the code before adding your header?

Comment: Its exactly the same, just without the code between the <!-- Start Header --> and <!-- End Header -->

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5qzdmnny/2/ I commented out the header - it's still showing that the font is small whether or not the header is there.

Comment: Yes, when viewing it in jsfiddle, it jumps from 16px to 14px based on the responsive media query. But if you copy the code and send an actual test email with putsmail.com, you will see that there is something else going on. You can see it in the screen shots i posted.